# Are we allowed to write an improper integral in the form of sums of integral?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I have some missing points about improper integrals, for instance, are we allowed to say:

1) $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{log(x+7)}{x}dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{log(x+7)}{x}dx)$

Actually, it really makes sense for me. However, if this holds then the following should also be true:

I know $\int_{0}^{\infty}sinx$ diverges, but $\int_{0}^{\infty}sinx = \sum_{0}^{\infty} (\int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi (n+1)}sinx) = \sum_{0}^{\infty} 0 = 0.$

Why is this false? Maybe my problem is not about integrals, it is about series?

Comment: You should accept answers if you found them useful. Click the tick beside an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could have equally wrote
$$\int_0^\infty\sin x\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\sin x\,dx=2-2+2-2+2-\dots$$
which is Grandi's series, and can be made to sum to $0$ or $2$ depending on how you put the brackets, so is really divergent.

Never replace an infinite-domain integral with an infinite sum of finite-domain integrals *unless the integrand is non-negative over the entire domain*. So the first example would be fine.

Comment: Then is the following doable? $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\left | sinx \right |}{x} = \int_{1}^{\pi} \frac{\left | sinx \right |}{x} + \sum_{1}^{\infty}(\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\left | sinx \right |}{x}) $ Since the integrand is non-negative over the domain.

Comment: @BerkYıldız Yes, but it diverges anyway.